# Vue component not rendering in Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I have a Vue Component, that is simple like this:

```
<template>
    <h1>Teste</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    mounted() {
        console.log("Component mounted.");
    },
};
</script>
```

my app.js:

```
require("./bootstrap");

import { createApp } from "vue";

import ExampleComponent from "./components/ExampleComponent";

const app = createApp({});

app.component("ExampleComponent", ExampleComponent);
app.mount("#app");
```

and when i try to use this component in blade the component is not rendering, i try this way

```
  <div>
        <h1> <ExampleComponent></ExampleComponent> </h1>
  </div>
```

and this way

```
 <div>
        <h1> <ExampleComponent/> </h1>
 </div>
```

the blade is working fine, its just the Vue component that is not rendering

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you install Vue properly in Laravel project,
double check it and also check if JS files are loading

Answer (score 0):

you need to add id **app**
ex:

```
<div id="app">
<h1> <ExampleComponent/> </h1>
</div>
```

or

```
<div id="app">
    <h1> <ExampleComponent></ExampleComponent> </h1>
 </div>
```